# Flutter Image Loading in a List

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, crashlytics

I have an app which is integrated with Firebase crashlytics, and in the crashlytic logs I see this Fatal exception:

[image]

I am not sure about the image url and cannot be sure. but anyways it is throwing exception.

I tried to use try catch like this:

```
ImageProvider<Object> loadImage(String imageUrl) {
    try {
      return ExtendedNetworkImageProvider(
        imageUrl,
        cache: true,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      return const AssetImage('assets/df.png');

    }
  }
```

and it is called here inside a listview.builder:

```
CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: loadImage(
                            list[index].profilePicURL,),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                        radius: 25,
                        onBackgroundImageError: (as, sa) {},
                      ),
```

I don't know why this exception occurs, and also I am not able to reproduce it locally. Maybe the size of the list is huge or image url doesn't work. this exception occurs min 1k times in day.

Here the log level of crashlytics:

```
FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError;
```

Comment: You should use CachedNetworkImage, it handles success, loading and error state so you can give all 3 widgets and it will load network image efficiently for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this on your own. In `ListView.builder` you add `future: loadImage(list[index].profilePicURL)` in `FutureBuilder` .

Then at the builder you give it a function if there is data, the avatar will contain the image data on the firestore , if there is no data, leave the default image in your assets folder.

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
 return CircleAvatar(
   backgroundImage: snapshot.data!,
   backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
   radius: 25,
   onBackgroundImageError: (as, sa) {},
  );
} else {
  return const CircleAvatar(
   backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/df.png'),
   backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
   radius: 25,
  );
}
```